# Facebook app settings for phonegap hybrid app with FacebookConnect

Tags: cordova, facebook-sdk-3.0

I have set up an app to use Facebook login feature. It is working properly in web browser but it fails on the device by throwing the URL error.

What am I supposed to do to get this working?

Comment: Use this plugin for Facebook login https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin

Comment: Yes, I am using the same

Comment: Its working for me . Are you added facebookConnectPlugin.js in your page.

Comment: I have. It works on the browser when i host it on my local. But cant seem to get it to work on the device.

Comment: Can you show the error log

Comment: did you manage to get it to work?

Comment: Sadly, no. Ended up using Openfb.